# Self-signed SSL cert works in IE & curl but no modern browsers

Tags: windows, google-chrome, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm experiencing a somewhat perplexing issue with a self-signed SSL certificate that Windows recognizes as valid, but which no modern browsers will accept.

The certificate is present in the system certificate store (accessed via the Certificates snap-in in MMC), within both the Personal and Trusted Root Certification Authorities folders, and marked as valid.

[image: Certificate validation]

Per the utility [SSL Certificate Verifier](https://www.pkisolutions.com/tools/sslcertverifier/), the certificate and certificate chain are valid.

Here is its output:

```
**************************************************************************
Processing 'localhost'
**************************************************************************
Scan started: 21-09-2020 13:43:33
Generating connection string...
Connection string is: https://localhost:14006/
Entering certificate validation callback function...
Server returned 1 certificates.
Entering server certificate chain validation function...
Leaf certificate issued to: E=REDACTED, CN=localhost, O=localhost, L=New York, S=NY, C=US
Found Subject Alternative Names extension in the certificate.
Fetching SAN values:
DNS Name=localhost
DNS Name=127.0.0.1
DNS Name=::1
IP Address=0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
IP Address=127.0.0.1

Certificate chain successfully passed all checks.
Finished!
Scan ended: 21-09-2020 13:43:33
```

If I attempt to access the service using Internet Explorer or `curl`, I get the expected 200 result from the service.

[image: Response from IE]

[image: Response from curl]

However, if I try to access the service using Edge, Chrome, Opera, or Firefox, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`. Before adding the certificate to Firefox's certificate store, I got `PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR` but now that also throws `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

[image: Response from Edge]

There are no proxies or VPNs active on my system or anything else that would interfere with Windows' networking. I'm at a complete loss. What on earth is happening here and how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: A connection reset is done by the server while the certificate checking is done by the client. Thus your problem has nothing to do with the certificate being valid or not.

Comment: I appreciate the effort to help, but ERR_CONNECTION_RESET is a handshaking error, and is not thrown by the server.

Comment: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET means that the server has send a TCP RST packet. It is not a handshake error but will cause a handshake error - if the TLS handshake was even started already. But it has nothing to do with client having problems of verifying the server certificate.

Comment: Then why would it work fine in curl and IE but no other browsers?

Comment: I have no idea what kind of server this is, but browsers differ slightly both in TLS and HTTP behavior. For example a RST happens if some broken server does not properly read the clients HTTP request but sends an answer and then closes the connection. Depending on timing and client implementation this will cause a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in the clients or not. And this issue is completely outside of TLS, i.e. happens after the TLS handshake is completed.

Comment: I am trying a completely different self-signed certificate in IIS and am having the same problem. Works in curl and IE and nothing else.

Comment: Hard to tell without having something reproducible or at least a packet capture of the failed connection to determine where exactly it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same symptoms - IE and curl working. Chrome, Edge and Firefox not, all reporting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

Ultimately it was pinned down to a corrupt `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\SSL\00010002\Functions` key.

nmap reported a single cipher in use when it was broken:

```
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
```

Reloaded the key with a correct value:

```
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp384r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp384r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (ecdh_x25519) - A
```

The absence of the GCM ciphers is the likely cause, given [Chromium was reporting them as obsolete five years ago](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/145196/chrome-browser-reports-obsolete-cipher-aes-256-cbc-with-hmac-sha1).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on chrome where it said

> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

, turns out the error was with the certificate itself.

Try the to create a certificate with the below link:
[SSL Certificate](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec/)